# Ceres-Solver: is a mutable used by a residual functor good pratice? What are other alternatives?

Tags: c++, computer-vision, mutable, ceres-solver

As far as I understand, the interface of `Ceres` requires each residual to be defined as a functor where `operator()` is a `const` member function. Here is an example of what I'm interested in:

```
class some_residual
{
   public:
    template<typename type>
    bool operator()(const type* const some_params, type* residual) const;

    Eigen::MatrixXd m_M;/*The explanation follows. Nevermind its type, all
                          that matters is that it is not a raw buffer*/
};
```

Now, I am in a particular case where I need the "helper" matrix `m_M`, that I would like to use inside `operator()`. There are a few options for that, for example, I could declare it as `mutable Eigen::MatrixXd m_M;` or change it to `std::shared_ptr<Eigen::MatrixXd> m_pM;` and update `*mP` from inside `operator()` (or similarly, I could use a reference). As another alternative, I could just pass the data of this matrix as a raw C pointer to `operator()`, and fix them in the `Ceres` optimization.

I prefer to avoid raw pointers whenever I can, and I'm inclinded to think that using `mutable` is the best solution. Is that good or bad practice in general, and in particular, is it safe to use that with `Ceres`? What other alternatives do I have?

Comment: Functors are usually light weight objects and algorithms sometimes take advantage of this and copy the functor multiple times (eg recursive algorithms). You need to check the implementation details before passing a heavy object to such algorithms.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks. So in that case the `std::shared_ptr` member seems to be the better option.

Answer (score 2):

mutable is a bad idea.

The reason the call to operator() is const is because if you decide to use the same functor in multiple CostFunctions, or the same CostFunction in multiple ResidualBlocks, then you risk having race conditions if and when Ceres is using multiple threads to evaluate residuals/Jacobians.